# How can I get the data from one field of a firestore document?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm working on an app which scans a barcode and searches a firestore database for a document with an id that matches with the scanned barcode and then adds the data to a list of maps.

However I'm stuck since I don't know how to assign the value of only one of the fields from the document to the correct key in the maps

Here's the relevant code:

```
Future scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    var databaseSearchResult = firestore.collection("packages").document(barcode);
    String databaseID =
        firestore.collection("packages").document(barcode).documentID;
    if (databaseID == barcode) {
      setState(() {
        productList.add({
          "bruh": databaseSearchResult["bruh"],
          "bruh 2": databaseSearchResult["bruh 2"]
        });
      });
    }
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Object not found in database");
    }
    try {} on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() => this.barcode =
          'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
```

As always help is greatly appreciated and if possible please try to keep it simple, I'm pretty new to flutter and dart. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the data of the document but you are not doing it here. Try the code below:

```
Future scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    var databaseSearchResult = firestore.collection("packages").document(barcode);
    DocumentSnapshot documentData = await databaseSearchResult.get() //read the data from the document
    Map<String,dynamic> dataMap = documentData.data; //this returns the data as a map where keys are the field names and values are the values of that field
    String databaseID =
        firestore.collection("packages").document(barcode).documentID;
    if (databaseID == barcode) {
      setState(() {
        productList.add({
          "bruh": dataMap["bruh"], //you access the value of "bruh" field in your database
          "bruh 2": dataMap["bruh 2"]
        });
      });
    }
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Object not found in database");
    }
    try {} on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() => this.barcode =
          'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! There's definitely a lot I still have to learn about firestore. The solution worked perfectly

Comment: You can always have a look at the documentation. I’m happy I could help :)